# Gmail add-on says 'Invalid add-on' in one G Suite account (but not another)

Tags: gmail-addons

We've developed an add-on, but whenever we try to install it we get an 'Invalid add-on' message. This is when adding the ID directly into the Gmail 'Add-ons' tab.

I've copy-pasted it into another G Suite account, and it works fine. So I'm assuming the problem can't be with the code - it must be our account somehow.

Has anyone come across this? I've checked every API access setting I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this: we had marketplace apps set to whitelist-only, which apparently affects add-ons. Instructions for disabling are here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6089179?hl=en.